# How to bind kendo dropdown list inside angular ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

Actually i want to add same dropdown values based on the addition. but here the adding same dropdown but when i'm changing one dropdown it's changing for all the dropdown in same time.

Please help me anyone to achive this.

HTML Code:

```html
<div ng-repeat="serviceItems in serviceParameters | filter: headerFilter track by $index">
  <div class="row service-param-row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
      <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12  col-sm-12">Header</label>
      <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12  col-sm-12">
               <input type="text" placeholder= "key"  ng-model="serviceItems.labelName">
           </label>
      <label class=" col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-12  col-sm-12">             
               <label class="label label-info">{{serviceItems.paramTypeValue}}</label>
      </label>
      <label class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">             
               <select  k-option-label="'--Select Type--'" kendo-drop-down-list ng-model="adapterServiceFormData.headertype"  k-options="headertypelist" tabindex="6" ></select>              
           </label>
      <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12  col-sm-12">  
               <kendo-button  ng-click="removeServiceParameter()" type="button" class="cancel">
                            <span class="k-icon k-i-cancel"></span>
             </kendo-button>
           </label>
      <span ng-show="$last"> 
               <kendo-button  ng-click="addServiceParameter('', 'Header', '378e04cf-3124-44eb-86df-095bb08abc10')"><span class="k-icon k-i-plus"></span></kendo-button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/Efusi/26

Comment: seems something wrong with headertypelist data source you are generating

Comment: yeah i'm generating headertypelist $scope.headertypelistdata = [{'headertype':"Request", 'headerTypeId':'123'},{'headertype':"Response", 'headerTypeId':'568'}];
    
   $scope.headertypelist  = {
   dataSource : $scope.headertypelistdata,
   dataTextField : "headertype",
   dataValueField : "headerTypeId",
   optionLabel : "--Select Type--"
 };

Comment: @vishalsharma - Thank you so much

Comment: Solved ?? whats the issue ?

Comment: @vishalsharma - Trying to solve it. I will update you. Thanks

Comment: @vishalsharma - it's working in dojo but not working in my app. what could be reason. codes looks correct only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160610/discussion-between-vishal-sharma-and-bagya).